# What does "conjured out of nowhere to drag things to a resolution" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you please help me understand this bold sentence? Or rephrase it? It's difficult for me to understand this part of the sentence word by word. I think that the author says the Simpsons screenwriters were using something like deus ex machina to fix their plot holes.

> It’s not incidental that all three of those examples involve Homer.
>   Season 9 saw the show drop him into any situation on the flimsiest of
>   pretenses. He flies to Cuba with Mr. Burns. He climbs the tallest
>   mountain in the world. He crashes Moe’s car into a river to collect
>   the insurance money, swims out from the depths, and then breaks out of
>   jail. Those episodes don’t so much have plot holes as they do plot
>   canyons, where things that make no sense are either studiously ignored
>   or **conjured out of nowhere to drag things to a resolution.**
>
> [source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs9/)

Comment: "I think that the author says the Simpsons screenwriters were using something like deus ex machina to fix their plot holes." - You got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "resolution" is a way of finishing a story in a satisfying way. The problems set up in the story are solved in the resolution.

If a story is "dragged to a resolution" then reaching the resolution is difficult.

"Conjuring out of nowhere" describes a magic trick where the magician creates something by magic. For example the magician might make a rabbit appear in his hat "out of nowhere".  Here it is used metaphorically: things that make no sense (in the context of the story) happen to drag the story to a resolution.

As you say "the author says the Simpsons screenwriters were using something like deus ex machina to fix their plot holes."